# ruby rails Database time

Tags: ruby, database, datetime, time, activeadmin

I have created a model with arrival_time as a time

```
create_table :trains do |t|
  t.time :arrival_time
```

and I'm feeding data through a Admin panel

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs " Journey start from " do
  f.collection_select :start_station_id, Station.all, :id, :name, {prompt:"Select start Station"}   
  f.input :arrival_time
  f.input :departure_time
end
```

However, inputs for time column in database saving with a date [database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76RYW.png).
how do I prevent saving time with date?.

All I need is time on time column

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use `:date` type instead of `:time`

`:date` : Stores only a date (year, month, day)

`:time` : Stores only a time (hours, minutes, seconds)

For example:

```
create_table :trains do |t|
  t.date :arrival_time
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.but,  I want to Save time in to arrival_time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you used SQLite as database. If it was a case, even if you specify `t.time :arrival_time` in a migration file, SQLite will parse input time and store it in column `arrival_time` in format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`.

According to [Date and Time Datatype of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype), it will only store dates and time as `TEXT`, `REAL` or `INTEGER` value. Therefore, when you try to keep `14:15` for  `arrival_time` column SQLite will store something like `2000-01-01 14:15:00` instead.

My preference is to store the `arrival_time` as string. In case I need to display the `arrival_time` I can use `Time.parse` to convert it the Time for today or another day I want.

```
arrival_time = "14:15"
today = Time.now
# => 2019-04-26 22:14:08 +0700
Time.parse(arrival_time)
# => 2019-04-26 14:15:00 +0700

specific_date = DateTime.new(2017, 03, 06)
Time.parse(arrival_time, specific_date)
# => 2017-03-06 14:15:00 +0700
```

Refer to [Time.parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse)